# Trying to print positions from matrix and put commas between them

Tags: r

I'm trying to print the positions of a matrix and make it easier for the reader of the printed text to understand that a pair of numbers corresponds to one position in the given matrix (row and column). However, the print looks more like this for 3 positions: 1 5 3 6 8 6

I would be nice to print it like this: [1,5], [3, 6], etc.

```
#Creating matrix 1
matrix1 <- matrix(data = 1:16, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
matrix1

#Creating a second matrix
matrix2 <- matrix(data = 2, nrow = 2, ncol = 8)
matrix2

#Matrix multiplication
matrix3 <- matrix1 %*% matrix2
matrix3

#Storing the positions of the highest values in matrix 3
position_matrix3 <- which(matrix3 == max(matrix3), arr.ind = TRUE)

#Since there are several "62"s in matrix 3, I tell R to only take the first value from position_matrix3
value_matrix3 <- matrix3[position_matrix3[1,1]]

#Here I want to print the one value (62) and show all the positions of 62 in the following [8, 8].... etc.

cat("The position of the maximum value in matrix3 are", position_matrix3, "and the corresponding value is", 
    value_matrix3)
```

Output:

```
The position of the maximum value in matrix3 are 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 and the corresponding value is 62
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
cat("The position of the maximum value in matrix3 are", value_matrix3, "and the corresponding value is", 
    paste0("[",position_matrix3[,1],",",position_matrix3[,2],"]")
)
```